# unresolved external symbol _DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, driver, setupapi

For devices attached to my machine I want to retrieve device-property **Bus Reported Device Description**. For this purpose I use function [SetupDiGetDeviceProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff551963) of [Setup API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi). In *devpkey.h* I found the defintion **DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc**.

But if I use **DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc** I receive *unresolved external symbol _DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc* while linking.

Here is my code (only included minimal code to reproduce issue):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <devpropdef.h>
#include <devpkey.h>

int main()
{
    DEVPROPKEY x = DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the full error code:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix this issue you need to include *initguid.h*. This include must before *devpropdef.h* and *devpkey.h*.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <initguid.h>   // include before devpropdef.h
#include <Windows.h>
#include <devpropdef.h>
#include <devpkey.h>

int main()
{
    DEVPROPKEY x = DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc;

    return 0;
}
```