# Get "Bus reported device description" from USB device connected to Com Port in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port, usbserial

Our device internally hooks up a serial port device using a USB to serial converter. We can program the FTDI chip in it and think that we can identify it using a device description that we choose.

As I plug in my USB to serial converter, windows initially shows this raw device description in a popup. When the driver is installed it will change to the driver description, which is the FTDI driver description.
I can see the description in de USB serial Converter under the "Universal Serial Bus controllers" as "Bus reported device description", but don't know how to get the COM port in c# that belong to that USB device.

First I was using SerialPort.GetPortNames();, but that doesn't have any information about the USB device.
Then I tried the solution in: [How to get Bus Reported Device Description using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732291/how-to-get-bus-reported-device-description-using-c-sharp)
But the "Bus reported device description" seems to be from the com-port and not the underlying USB device.

So my question is: How can I get the comport (COM??) that is linked to our USB controller that has the "Bus reported device description" that I programmed into this USB to serial converter chip.

Comment: See the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957066/serial-to-usb-cable-from-a-scale-to-pc-some-values-are-just-question-marks/65971845#65971845 (HelperSerialPort.cs => GetComPortInfo)

Comment: It's not C#, but these articles may be helpful. [How to get the Bus reported device description of a device?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/35ad96d5-df46-469d-be06-5ab78f090b31/), [How do I retreive a USB "Bus reported device description"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d164feb6-0f6d-4e5a-97cd-044b2b4d6770/), [How to get extended port information when enumerating ports using Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62266445/9014308), [SetupDiGetDeviceProperty usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438366/9014308)